# Linker command fail with a bunch of undefined reference

Tags: c++, makefile, clang, clang++, libc++

I try to compile a project using clang and libc++. Here is my makefile :

```
EXEC = ModularMadness
SRCDIR = src/
INC =-I$(SRCDIR)
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)*.cpp) $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)*/*.cpp)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

CXX = clang++
CXX_FLAGS = -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ $(INC)

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXEC)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXX_FLAGS) $< -o $@

.PHONY: all clean

clean:
    @echo Cleaning...
    @rm -f $(EXEC) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo done
```

The .o files creation works fine, but I ran in multiple error like 
`In function 'std::__1::weak_ptr<module::Module>::lock() const': undefined reference to 'std::__1::__shared_weak_count::lock()'` during linker command.

Could someone help me understanding what's the problem here ?

---

#### Note

This makefile run perfectly on OS X.

Comment: what is 1y? Also you lack the linker flags... could you post the compile line?

Comment: 1y is for c++14 in clang version 3.14 or earlier ([clang](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html)). And you where right I missed the -`lc++` flag. My bad.

Comment: note - for `clang++` 'dialect' and library options, I would always recommend making them part of the `CXX` variable (keep `CC` for C compilers). The `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++` also affect linking.

Answer (score 1):

I missed the linker flag `-lc++`... Thank you [perencia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2737046/perencia).

Here is the working makefile :

```
EXEC = ModularMadness
SRCDIR = src/
INC =-I$(SRCDIR)
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)*.cpp) $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)*/*.cpp)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

CXX = clang++
CXX_FLAGS = -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ $(INC)

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXEC) -lc++ # Here

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXX_FLAGS) $< -o $@

.PHONY: all clean

clean:
    @echo Cleaning...
    @rm -f $(EXEC) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo done
```